# Styling input field's placeholder with CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Is it possible to have HTML effects in a `input` field's placeholder attribute? For example, can the following be the output of a input field placeholder?

> normal **bold**

The placeholder can be customized using CSS with `::placeholder` but it applies to all the text inside it. How to tweak it like it were HTML?

Comment: What do you mean by "placeholder"?

Comment: If you scope it well, you should be able to achieve it easily. If you could provide a demo, I’d be glad to demonstrate.

Comment: @zero298 -- like `<input type="text" name="city" placeholder="Enter your city">` See [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-placeholder)

Comment: placeholder - like <input type='text' placeholder='my first-name field'> - but have the phrase "first-name" bolded or a different color, font, etc.

Answer (score 5):

I guess you can create a "placeholder" like effect to do what you want to do. Like this:

```css
.inputBox {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.placeholder {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.85;
}

.inputBox input:focus+.placeholder {
  display: none;
}

.inputBox input:valid+.placeholder {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="inputBox">
  <input type="text" required />
  <div class="placeholder"><span style="font-weight: bold">Bold</span> <span>Text</span><!-- your html here --></div>
</div>
```

Comment: ok that is pretty clever!   i though you were going to tell me something like "wait six months for html6".